# How to install OpenCV+Python on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV+Python on Mac. I am trying to do this in six steps by running commands at terminal (after step2):

**Step1:** Install Xcode

**Step2:** Install Homebrew

**Step3: Install Python2 and Python3**

1) `brew install python python3`

2) `brew linkapps python`

```
brew linkapps python3
```

4) `which python`

```
which python3
```

**Step4:** Install Python libraries by installing a virtual environment

**Step5:** Install OpenCV

**Step6:** Symlink OpenCV+Python to virtual environment

The problem is that `which python` must give output `/usr/local/bin/python` and not `/usr/bin/python` as it gives by default so that the virtual environment can be installed to install then the Python libraries.

I removed the link by running `unlink /usr/bin/python` and I created a symlink by running `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python /usr/bin/python` (python and python3 are installed by default at `/usr/local/Cellar/`).

However now `which python` gives me no output even though I have created the symlink. Why is this?

**How can I change the output of `which` command to install finally OpenCV+Python on Mac?**

Any better idea to install OpenCV+Python on Mac with most of the useful libraries or virtual environments etc? (Obviously I know how to do the installation without all these)

*P.S. I followed this link: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-macos/*

Comment: Does your environment PATH variable contain the "/usr/local/bin/" dir?

Comment: I have written 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' at my bash_profile and when I open '/etc/paths/' then '/usr/local/bin' is higher than 'usr/bin'. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You just said `which python` gives you not output, that means `python` executable is not present within directories listed in your PATH variable. So the order doesn't matter. Also on Step 4 why are you stating that python must necessarily be pointed at /usr/local/bin/python?

Comment: Ok, so how can I make it to be present within directories listed in my PATH variable please?

Comment: Python must point at /usr/local/bin/python because otherwise the virtual environment cannot be installed and specifically `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` cannot be executed at the bash_profile. Also if python points at at /usr/local/bin/python then it means that I am using the system version and not the homebrew version.

Comment: `brew install opencv3 --with-python3`

Comment: Haha, ok, thanks but the issue is to install also the virtual environment, the libraries etc. So how did you do this?

Comment: I have no experience with virtual environment, but you can refer to [this link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/) for an instruction.

Answer (score 1):

The officially recommended python packaging tool is `pipenv`. One example of a workflow you could use to make a virtual environment with the exact libraries your project needs as well as ensuring security is this:

```
$ brew install pipenv
$ cd /path/to/project
$ pipenv --three
$ pipenv install opencv-python
```

And after you write your code in, say, `project.py`

```
$ pipenv run python3 project.py
```

More info on the [pipenv site](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did not solve the problem with `which output` even though I discuss it with really experienced people.

Finally, I downloaded PyCharm and I did the following:

1) Installed pip (Python package manager) by opening a project at PyCharm and going to PyCharm Community Edition (top bar) -> Preferences -> Project -> Project interpreter -> Press '+' -> Search and find pip (with the search bar) -> Press 'Install Package'

2) Type and enter `pip install opencv-python` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python) at the terminal

3) Follow the process at (1) to install/import opencv-python in PyCharm

4) Write `import cv2` at the top of your source code

By not implementing the more extensive installation process described by the links that I posted above, I did not install the virtual environment which is highly recommended in order to avoid conflicts between various projects. But I think that I can make it without it for the moment!

Answer (score 0):

***Install OpenCV 'You must have Python3 installed'***

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).