# Python and OpenCV: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I was setting up OpenCV and downloaded the latest version of Python, but when I write `import cv2`, I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

[This image is the error I'm getting in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeWag.png)

[This is what it says when I try to redownload OpenCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM7aK.png)

I'm running on the latest version of MacOS. Does anyone know how to solve this?

I've already tried redownloading OpenCV but that doesn't seem to be working and I always continue to get the same error.

Comment: Your installation command is errorneous. Please read the alternatives described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47332282/18667225 ! Btw please don't post error messages as screenshots. Use plain text with code markups instead. [ask]